# ImportError with dask.distributed

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, dask-distributed

I am trying to import dask.distributed package, but I keep getting this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_to_dsk'. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error, there were some outdated packages including imageio which needed upgrade to work with dask.distributed and dask.dataframe.